# how is the ordering of automatic arrays done in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cygwin

Let say I have three arrays `a1[],a2[] and a3[]`. All three arrays(a1,a2,a3) point to the first element of their respective array.
While implementing code, I declared:

`int a1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int a2[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int a3[]={1,2,3,4,5};`

when I printed their addresses, sequencing of address starts as

`(a3+0)=2337376 :: (a3+1)=2337380 :: (a3+2)=2337384 :: (a3+3)=2337388 :: (a3+4)=2337392
(a2+0)=2337396 :: (a2+1)=2337400 :: (a2+2)=2337404 :: (a2+3)=2337408 :: (a2+4)=2337412
(a1+0)=2337416 :: (a1+1)=2337420 :: (a1+2)=2337424 :: (a1+4)=2337428 :: (a1+4)=2337432`

My question is, I have declared a1 before a2 and a3. but addresses for a1 are located **after** a3 and a2. If a1 is declared first, its address should have the minimum value among a2 and a3 or thinking in different way there should be no relation among addresses of a1, a2 and a3. But you can see addressing of a2 started just after a3 and addressing of a1 is started just after a2. Why?

the code I have used is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,a1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p1=a1;
    printf("\n Addresses of 1st array:\n");
    for( i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",(p1+i));
    }
    int a2[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p2=a2;
    printf("\n Addresses of 2nd array:\n");
    for( i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",(p2+i));
    }
    int a3[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p3=a3;
    printf("\n Addresses of 3rd array:\n");
    for( i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",(p3+i));
    }

}
```

And output I got is:

```
 Addresses of 1st array:
2337440 2337444 2337448 2337452 2337456
 Addresses of 2nd array:
2337408 2337412 2337416 2337420 2337424
 Addresses of 3rd array:
2337376 2337380 2337384 2337388 2337392
```

I'm using CYGWIN compiler

Comment: The common implementation is to store auto variables on the stack. And almost always, the stack grows from higher addresses to lower addresses. That is, space is made on the top of the stack for a push operation by subtracting the data size from the current top of the stack. The compiler is not bound to order the storage of variables in the same order as you have listed in your C code. It can do whatever it thinks is best. But in this case it does appear to be laid out in that same order - earlier variables are pushed onto the stack first resulting in those having higher addresses.

Comment: I wanted to understand the behavior of storage stack. Now I'm quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does sequencing of address-allocation of arrays is done in C?

The language does not specify how unrelated arrays are allocated. The language requires that items in a single array have a certain sequence of addresses. Given

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
```

The language guarantees that

```
a < a+1
a+1 < a+2
```

and

```
numerical value of (a+1) - numerical value of (a) == sizeof(int)
numerical value of (a+2) - numerical value of (a+1) == sizeof(int)
```

However, given

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
int b[] = {100, 200, 300};
```

the language makes no promises about the relationship between `a+1` and `b+1`. The compiler is free to choose how it allocates memory for `a` and `b`.

By examining the values of the addresses of the elements of `a` and `b`, one can make judgments about how a compiler is allocating memory for the arrays. But that's of interest only if you are interested in figuring out how a compiler works. As a regular user of the language, you shouldn't concern yourself with those relationships, and **definitely not write any program that depends on those relationships**.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are confusing arrays and pointers. While they behave very similarly in C, they are not the same thing. This can been quite easily in your example by the fact that you assigned your array to a pointer in order to print its address, thus, effectively, casting it.

The relevant part of that distinction is that when you define an array via:

```
int a1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

`a1` is defined with the actual size of the entire array (i.e. - 5 ints). `a1` has no address of its own, and casting it to a pointer actually gives the address of its first element (i.e. `(int*)a1 == &a1[0]`).

Now to your actual question. The order local variables are defined on the stack is undefined by C. It may go up, as you expect it to. It may also go down. It may also be random. If the compiler decides two variables are never used at the same time, it may even assign both the same address. If this is not a general understanding question, if there is something that you are trying to achieve by understanding the ordering, my best advise for you is **don't**.

As for the actual sequence: the stack on most platforms, and Intel in particular, grows downward. This means that lower addresses are considered "later" than higher addresses. Your compiler, quite reasonably, placed the arrays in sequence (i.e. - growing downward).

None of the above applies to the order of elements of a single array. Inside a single array, the order of the elements is well defined, and has to be in ascending order. The compiler is not given any leeway by the standard on that point, and you are quite welcome to rely on it (though I fail to see why you'd want to). This does not contradict what I said above, because all the elements of a single array are allocated on the stack together, and therefor the internal ordering has no meaning beyond that which we assign to them.

Comment: "a1 has no address of its own" Wrong. `a1` certainly does have an address of its own, which happens to be the same as the address of its first element.